# What's the connection string for LDAP?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Here how I need to use it:

```
string tmpDirectory = String.Format("LDAP://ou={0},dc={1},dc={2}", 
                                    parentOrganizationUnit,
                                    domainName,
                                    domainExtension
);
```

When I try to run some code using this connection, I get an exception. ([See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359151/the-specified-domain-either-does-not-exist-or-could-not-be-contacted)).

I've been told I need to provide the connection string with credentials - a username and a password.

What's the connection string like? I need the exact syntax. :) Thanks!

I'm using Windows Server 2003 and Active Directory.

Answer (score 3):

The credentials don't go into the connection string, but are separate parameters on [another overload of the `DirectoryEntry` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw8k1as4.aspx):

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry(tmpDirectory, "username", "password");
```