# LDAP Connection String

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have this LDAP Connection string: `connectionString="LDAP://username:password@10.10.10.246:389/DC=ABC,DC=local"`

Active directory server is `ABC.local` with IP `10.10.10.246`.

I am using this code to read properties from active directory:

```
MembershipSection membershipSection = (MembershipSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");
    string defaultProvider = membershipSection.DefaultProvider;
ProviderSettings providerSettings = membershipSection.Providers[defaultProvider];
string connectionStringName = providerSettings.Parameters["connectionStringName"];
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(connectionString);
string name = ent.Properties["l"].Value.ToString();
string Language = ent.Properties["st"].Value.ToString();
```

but an error appears saying `"The server is not operational."`. Am I doing anything wrog with connection string or what is happening. an you help me please?

Comment: Is that error message an application message or is it coming direct from an exception? If the former, what is the actual exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a explanation about [LDAP connection string](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string) in ServerFault and here in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359721/whats-the-connection-string-for-ldap)

You should not use IP address in your connection string, that's a bad habit.
In your case, I think it shoud be something like that : `LDAP://ABC.local/DC=ABC,DC=local`.

This can be use each time you need to search an object in your AD : `LDAP://OU=Users,DC=ABC,DC=local` and so on.

Concerning authentication, there is [an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359721/whats-the-connection-string-for-ldap), that gives you:

`DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionString, username, password);`

I hope that helped.

Comment: The LDAP URL without a hostname only works if the LDAP server is running on the local host. Using an IP address instead of a hostname does not cause this problem. There is no evidence of an authentication error here. -1

Comment: He've never mention that his server hasn't the AD feature... I suggested a solution. And using an IP address is not the best solution at all.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string is incorrect, you should use another one and initialize DirectoryEntry entry by a different way:

```
string connectionString="LDAP://10.10.10.246/DC=ABC,DC=com"; // You can use also simple "LDAP://DC=ABC,DC=com" without IP
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry(connectionString, userName, password);
string name = ent.Properties["name"].Value.ToString(); // Note that property 'l' has friendly name 'City', it's unavailable for domain object!
```

Comment: You can only omit the IP address from the URL if the LDAP server is running in the same host. There is no evidence here of an authentication problem. -1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i have never seen that user logon can be passed in PATH parameter, its common practice to set user name and password in new Directory Entry call as addition params but not in the path and it seems to me that it is the problem in this code. MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180841(v=vs.80).aspx

Of course, using domain name or server name instead of IP is in preference